# Как работает это логическое выражение?

Tags: c

Как будет выполняться данный кусочек кода?

```
a=1;b=-1;
if (!a && b)
...
```

Comment: все что не 0 - истина

Answer (score 5):

`!a` равно *false*, дальше `false && b` равно `false`, по определению.

Comment: унарные опператоры выполняются всегда раньше чем логические?

Comment: погда ещё вопросец, если будет такакя запись, то `a=-1; b=1; if (!a && b)`, то получится 1?

Comment: ок, т.е. всё что не 0 трактуется как 1?

Answer (score 2):

`a` - истина, `!a` - ложь.
Поэтому до обработки `b` дело не дойдёт, а оператор или группа операторов, относящихся к if, выполняться не будут.

Answer (score 1):

Если a = false и b = true (и только в таком случает!), то код что внутри if - будет выполнятся код .